# Seaborn Facet Grid 'col=' not creating plots side by side in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I'm trying to plot two seaborn catplots side by side and not one on top of the other. In order to not share the x axis I had to create a FacetGrid instance and use the '*.map_dataframe*' function to produce two plots but it has produced them one above the other. (I was able to create the plots side by side just by using 'sns.catplot' however the 'sharex=False' argument didn't work and I ended up with all of the values across both x-axes.)

Here is my code:

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data = pcd_data,  col = 'Multi Storey Property')
grid.map_dataframe(sns.catplot, kind = 'bar', x="House Type ",
                   y="Percentage",  height = 6, hue="Last Balance Range Sort", 
                   palette = 'pastel', alpha = 0.6)
plt.close(1)
plt.show()
```

And it has produced the following:

[image: Seaborn Facet Grid Rows not Columns]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Python 3.8.3 Anaconda. Conda 4.9.1

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide the columns to `catplot`, using an example dataset:

```
import seaborn as sns
data = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
data = data.groupby(["diet","kind","time"])["pulse"].agg("mean").reset_index()
data.head()

    diet    kind    time    pulse
0   no fat  rest    1 min   91.8
1   no fat  rest    15 min  92.2
2   no fat  rest    30 min  93.0
3   no fat  walking 1 min   95.6
4   no fat  walking 15 min  98.6

sns.catplot(x='kind',y='pulse',hue='time',kind='bar',col='diet',data=data)
```

[image]

If you have different x-axis, you can make the x label a string:

```
data = data[~((data.diet=="no fat") & (data.kind=="rest"))]
data['kind'] = data['kind'].astype('str')
```

And similar to @Alex solution, you call facet and map barplot onto it, the first argument is for x-axis, 2nd y-axis and 3rd hue:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="diet",sharex=False,sharey=False)
g.map(sns.barplot, "kind", "pulse",'time',hue_order=data.time.unique())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I may not have described the problem very well. My issue is that I wanted my plots side-by-side, like yours, but also to not necessarilly have the same labels on the x axis. E.g. in your example imagine hypothetically the 'diet = low fat' group had no data for 'kind = rest' so that should be left out of the  x axis for  the graph on the right hand side. In my example the 'sharex = False' parameter did not work.

Comment: ok yeah.. i edited my answer, you need to use facet.. see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `catplot` which returns a `FacetGrid`. Instead you should use `sns.barplot` directly:

```py
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data=pcd_data, col="Multi Storey Property")
grid.map_dataframe(
    sns.barplot,
    x="House Type ",
    y="Percentage",
    hue="Last Balance Range Sort",
    palette="pastel",
    alpha=0.6,
)
grid.set_axis_labels("House Type", "Percentage")
grid.add_legend()
```